# Prime number checker error c++

Tags: c++

I've programmed java for some time, and I've just started c++.
I decided to make a prime number checker, but for some reason it doesn't print out if it's a prime number or not.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int prime;

int main()
{
  while(true)
  {
    int primeChecker;
    cout << "Enter a number to check if it is prime" << endl;

    cin >> prime;

    for(int i = 2; i <= (1/2)*prime; i++){
        cout << "Working" << endl;
        if(prime % i == 0){
            cout << "This number is not prime" << endl;
            primeChecker+=1;
        }
    }
    if(primeChecker == 0){
      cout << "This number is prime" << endl;
    }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `(1/2)` is `0`.

Comment: You may want to make a function isPrime, which returns bool. The input/output code can just call it, and have an easy if/else check. And you probably want upper_bound = sqrt(number). You can check %2, then start with 3 and incriment by 2 (no reason to check any even numbers other than 2). I do not like that you named your variable "prime" when you do not know what it is yet, nor that you made it global. Maybe also validate inputs, and provide a way to exit.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize primechecker with 0. Also write i<=prime/2 instead of i<=(1/2)prime. Again you should use break when you find out the number is not a prime. Also you need to check for 1. I think this is what you tried to write-

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int prime;

int main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        int primeChecker=0;
        cout << "Enter a number to check if it is prime" << endl;
        cin >> prime;
        if(prime==1)
        {
            cout << "This number is not prime" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i = 2; i <= prime/2; i++)
            {
                cout << "Working" << endl;
                if(prime % i == 0)
                {
                cout << "This number is not prime" << endl;
                primeChecker+=1;
                break;
                }
            }
            if(primeChecker == 0)
            {
                cout << "This number is prime" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code will take more time for larger values. I'd suggest you to check up to square root of prime to confirm whether the number is prime or not. Good luck!